# How do I implore someone to "Take Action Now" in Spanish

Tags: traducción

I believe that "imperative" is the tense of the phrase. It's copy for a button inviting a user to "take action now".

I came up with:

> Debe Actuar Ahora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ahora mismo](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/ahora%20mismo) is more affirmative than [ahora](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/ahora).

If you are in Mexico, don't use "ahorita" because that would have the opposite effect. :)

Comment: I haven't heard 'ahorita' before. Does it refer to a "little now", like within a small moment? I'd love to see some more about how it would have the opposite effect in Mexico. How so?

Comment: You would think it would mean sooner, but for some reason in Mexico, it's the opposite.  It means "in a little bit, not just right now. Please wait a little."

Answer (score 2):

The sentence "Debe actuar ahora" (*You must/have to act now*) is in the present indicative, not in the imperative mood.

This would be the imperative mood: "Actúe ahora."

However, the effect of "Debe actuar ahora" is imperative. It sounds a bit less forceful than the imperative mood.

Instead of "ahora" or "ahora mismo", "ya" or "ya mismo" can also be used, which might sound slightly more urgent.